# Why do I have a segmentation fault in recursive assembly function?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86-64, stack-frame

Hi I write a Fibonacci recursive code in assembly with the amd64 abi calling convention, but I always get segmentation fault :/
I compile it with:

nasm -f elf64 -o fibo.o fibonacci.asm

ld -o fibo fibo.o

./fibo

I have no compiling errors but a segmentation error, so I guess something went wrong with my Stackframes.

Thanks for any help :)

```
SECTION .data

; define the fibonacci number that should be calculated
n:      dq   10

SECTION .text

global _start

_start:
    ; call Fibonacci function f(n)
    mov     rdi, [n]    ; parameter: fibonacci number to calculate
    call    f           ; call function

    ; print calculated Fibonacci number on stdout
    ;call    printnumber

    ; exit process with exit code 0
    mov     rax, 60
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall

; f: Calculates a Fibonacci number
;   f(n) = {n, if n<=1; f(n-1)+f(n-2), else}.
;   Parameter: Integer n >= 0, passed on stack
;   Returns:   Fibonacci number f(n), returned in rax
f:
    push rbp            ; neuen stackframe
    mov rbp, rsp        
    push rdi            ; rdi auf stack speichern
    add rbp, 16         ; 
    mov rdi, [rbp]      ; rdi = parameter

    cmp rdi, 1          ; check for base case
    jle base            ; n <= 1

    dec  rdi            ; n-1
    push rdi
    call f              ; f(n-1)
    pop rdi

    dec  rdi            ; n-2
    push rdi
    call f              ; f(n-2)
    pop rdi
    pop rdi
    add rax, rdi

    jmp end
base: 
    mov rax, 1

end:
    pop rdi
    pop rbp
    mov rsp, rbp

    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

You set up the stack frame in `f` correctly, but then you start going wrong with the addition to `rbp`.  You should leave `rbp` alone, and add the offset on the variable fetch instead:

```
push rdi
move rdi,[rbp+16]
```

You exit sequence is wrong.  The addition of 16 to rbp in the entry is a problem here (resolved by not changing rbp) and you have the `rsp` restoration in the wrong place.

```
pop rdi
mov rsp,rbp    ; Unnecessary here (see below)
pop rbp
ret
```

However, since you never change `rsp` to allocate storage for local variables, the move to `rsp` is unnecessary and can be omitted.

Note that there are other issues with the code not related to the entry/exit sequence and crash.